# setting strong parameters for translated attributes and arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using the `mobility` gem and ActiveStorage together, the Rails guide suggestion of setting strong parameters for the stored objects in a has may relation as

```
    def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:title, :content, images: [])
    end
```

However, having the requirement to establish params that are translated, a second  collection of strong parameters is required.

```
translated_params = (I18n.available_locales.map do |l|
  [:"element_#{Mobility.normalize_locale(l)}"]
end.flatten)
params.require(:component).permit(:element, :tag_ids, :reference_ids, translated_params, documents: [])
```

renders.  However, the following syntax

```
params.require(:vocabular).permit(:element, :tag_ids, :reference_ids, documents: [], translated_params)
```

generates an error `syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting => ...cuments: [], translated_params)`

It is surprising, as there is no immediate syntaxic error; it is more like a gotcha.
Why is ruby interpreting the requirement to have a parenthesis - or to place explicitely declared arrays at the end of the arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it easy to see:

```rb
def permit *filters
  filters
end

>> permit(:positional_arg)
=> [:positional_arg]

>> permit(:positional_arg, keyword: :arg)
=> [:positional_arg, {:keyword=>:arg}]

>> permit(:positional_arg, keyword: :arg, :err)
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/irb/workspace.rb:119:in `eval': (irb):6: 
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting => (SyntaxError)
...ional_arg, keyword: :arg, :err)
...                              ^
```

`:err)` it's a syntax error because ruby is expecting `=>`, as in key/value pair for another keyword argument, but you gave it `)` instead.

```rb
>> permit(:positional_arg, keyword: :arg, not: :err)
=> [:positional_arg, {:keyword=>:arg, :not=>:err}]
#                    ^                          ^
# see how it's part of a single hash
```

It has nothing to do with arguments really, it's not a valid syntax in general:

```rb
>> [one: :two, :three]
syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting => (SyntaxError)
[one: :two, :three]
                  ^
```

it's the same as doing this:

```
>> {one: :two, :three} 
syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting => (SyntaxError)
{one: :two, :three}
                  ^
```

---

`translated_params` is an array and it should be in front of keyword arguments. Because actual `permit` method [flattens](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4.3/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L623) all the arguments there is no need to splat `*` the array.

If you're just trying to keep `translated_params` separate, you can make it the very first argument:

```rb
params.require(:vocabular)
  .permit(translated_params, :element, :tag_ids, :reference_ids, documents: [])
```

or maybe like this:

```rb
params.require(:vocabular)
  .permit([:element, :tag_ids, :reference_ids, documents: []], translated_params)
```

Just to be clear, this works for `permit` method, it doesn't work for everything.

Comment: Very well laid out response.  Illuminating.

Comment: One tiny detail here is that these aren't *real* keyword arguments. What is actually happening is that Rails will let you omit the brackets around a hash when its the last argument - however the hash is still a positional argument.